# Android- unknown webview crash reason

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception

I have a class that is its own activity that basically i use to host a webview. It works fine on most devices but on the motorolla droid bionic it farted out this error every once in a while when loading the page.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2384)
at android.webkit.WebView.onScrollChanged(WebView.java:4820)
at android.view.View.scrollTo(View.java:5016)
at android.webkit.WebView.onOverScrolled(WebView.java:2603) 
at android.view.View.overScrollBy(View.java:8890)
at android.webkit.WebView.computeScroll(WebView.java:3004)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1562)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2106)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1562)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1298)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1911)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After trouble shooting with the debugger I just cant get my head around where the nullpointer is coming from.....anyone have similar problems on the droid bionic? or other devices for that matter.

Comment: I'm having this problem too.  It crashes if I back out of the Activity while scrolling.  Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: No Ive never been able to catch whats causing the crash however when I add a javascript interface and add some buttons on my actual webpage I created a javascript function that calls my native function which will call finish. The best thing I can think to do is to put the close button you have on your webpage in an extremely easy place to view. When you push the close button in my webview that is actually on my webpage it now closes the webview activity I set up by calling finish and it no longer crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but as I just faced this same exception; I thought it would be helpful to share my conclusion.

I had this Activity, with a very simple Layout - where the activity content view was a single instance of a WebView.

It was set like this:

```
onStart()
{
    this.setContentView(this.browser);
}
```

and, I had this in the onStop method of my Activity:

```
onStop()
{
    this.browser.destroy()
}
```

My application logic was designed in a way that this activity had to start and stop many times...so...the very first time it started and stopped, everything went fine...but after the 2nd execution of "onStart" I had the exception.

So, I removed the call to "this.browser.destroy()" and everything worked...I suppose that killed my object and thus I had a reference to null...

So, if you're getting this, you're losing the valid reference to some view in your layout...just examine your code and try to find where is it that it is being "null-ed".

Comment: Hey thanks for posting an answer on that. Im doing something similar in my app where Im destroying the webview in an onpause because I reuse the activity anywhere I need to view the web. Ill try removing my destroy calls to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

you need remove WebView from layout before call destroy

> Destroy the internal state of the WebView. This method should be called after the WebView has been removed from the view system. No other methods may be called on a WebView after destroy.